# Детский вопрос: прилагательное от слова «шпиц»

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, прилагательные

Девочка (семь лет) увидела пушистого померанского [шпица](https://spitz-sobaka.ru/poroda/okrasy-shpitsev/). Диалог был приблизительно таким:

— Какая красивая собачка, как медвежонок. Только цвет лисий.
— Это шпиц. Окраска этой собаки называется рыжая или персиковая.
— А какой еще бывает шпицный цвет?
— Шпицный? Так говорить неправильно. Черный, белый, коричневый, бывают пятнистые...
— А как правильно?

Объяснила ребенку, что можно сказать *окраска шпица, хозяйка шпица*.
Неужели нет правильного прилагательного?

Answer (score 3):

Есть выбор между "притяжательным" вариантом **шпичий** (ср. заячий, птичий хвост) и более отвлечённым **шпицевый** (ср. *тигровый окрас* vs тигриный коготь). В контексте конкретного цвета, присущего *тому или иному* шпицу (как в вопросе), выбор - в пользу первого варианта.

Comment: Я думаю, что "шпицевый" скорее подошло бы к названию цвета, характеристике окраса и т.п. (можно говорить о других животных "шпицевого окраса"). Но в контексте "какой бывает шпицевый цвет?" (то есть какого цвета могут быть померанские шпицы) этот вариант вряд ли возможен.

Comment: Согласен. Я не совсем внимательно отнёсся к тексту и отреагировал на заголовок в смысле "какое прилагательное обозначает цвет, присущий всем шпицам" - в собаках не разбираюсь и предположил, что все шпицы - одного характерного цвета. Уточняю выбор из двух слов для имеющегося контекста.

Comment: *вариантом шпичий* - Только нет это! Зачем там Ч? У "волчий", "собачий" - из чередования К/Ч, У "заячий", "паячий" - из суффикса (заяц - он из "заяти" - петлять), а шпиц-то несчастный как в этом списке оказался?! Сравните - "куций" - чередования нет.

Comment: @behemothus -чий выглядит намного привычнее в русском языке. Ср. овца — овечий, индеец — индеечий, скворец — скворечий, девица — девичий, лисица — лисичий, птица — птичий. На -ций в русском вообще никакие слова не заканчиваются, кроме разве химических элементов и двух-трёх заимствований (слова *куций* я в орфографическом словаре не нашёл).

Answer (score 1):

"Правильного" нет, это да. 
Но если уж очень надо, то ***"шпиций"*** (без Н - как "собачий", "лисий", "волчий"). "*Шпиций характер*" - пару раз встречал такое.